# sort.Interface as argument

Tags: go

```
func IsPalindrome(s sort.Interface) bool {
    for lo, hi := 0, s.Len()-1; lo < hi; {
        if s.Less(lo, hi) || s.Less(hi, lo) {
            return false
        }
        lo++
        hi--
    }
    return true
}
```

I am implementing a palindrome checker for any type which satisfy sort interface. I also have test case like this:

```
func TestIsPalindrome(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        a sort.Interface
        r bool
    }{
        {a: []int{1, 3, 1}, r: true},
        {a: "helloolled", r: true},
        {a: "The Go Programming Language", r: false},
    }

    for row, test := range tests {
        assert.Equal(t, test.r, IsPalindrome(test.a), "row: %d\n", row)
    }
}
```

but it complains that

```
cannot use []int literal (type []int) as type sort.Interface in field value:
    []int does not implement sort.Interface (missing Len method)
cannot use "helloolled" (type string) as type sort.Interface in field value:
    string does not implement sort.Interface (missing Len method)
....
```

I think []int is a slice, "helloolled" is string, both should have Len method.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: "both should have Len method" - that may be. What about `Less`? (and `Swap`, which you are not using here)

Comment: Neither slice nor string have Len method. Those are builtin types that can be passed into the the `len` function however that does not mean that they have a `Len` method or that they implement a `Len` method. None of the [`builtin`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/) types have any methods, and also no *unnamed* (e.g. `[]string`) types have any methods, therefore they cannot implement *any* interface but the empty interface.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you so much for your help, I think I still have a long to go as a go newbie.

Comment: you can add filter to type by using "reflect " libary